# Truffle Migrate deployment issue - not getting results when I migrate

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, truffle

I've successfully deployed my SmartContracts locally to Ganache and want to now take it to the next level by testing them on ROPSTEN.

For some reason, even though I've done this a million times before with other projects, when I run

`truffle migrate --network ropsten`

I'm not getting *any* sort of results, which is to say I'm not getting errors, but its also just not succeeding. It just says:

```
Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang
```

...and puts me back at the prompt line, waiting for my next command.

My DEV ENVIRONMENT is:

- Operating System: Mac OS Catalina v.10.15.1
- Truffle Version (truffle version): v.5.0.34
- Node Version (node --version): v.10.16.3
- NPM Version (npm --version): v.6.14.4
- 

├─┬ @truffle/hdwallet-provider@1.0.35
│ └── web3@1.2.1 
├─┬ truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.17
│ └── web3@1.2.1 
└── web3@0.20.7

(Yes, I seem to have two versions of Web3 - but I don't think that's the problem...)

My `truffle-config.js` file looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');


module.exports = {

ropsten: {
  provider: function () {
      return new HDWalletProvider(
          process.env.GANACHE_MNENOMIC,
          "https://ropsten.infura.io/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}"
      )
  },
  network_id: 3,
  from: "0xB4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  gas: 8000000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  confirmations: 2, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  skipDryRun: true
},
```

My `.env` file has the `MNEMONIC`s and the `INFURA_API_KEY` which are all valid.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You need a faucet and get some funds on your ropsten address so that migration of contract is executed.